# How to remote login to an external site with login credentials?

Tags: python, nginx, web, proxy, server

I have the username/password credentials for a website, say http://website.com/login/. How do I proxy that website (with my own server) such that I programmatically pass my login credentials and using my proxy server, I can access the website without having to log in. In short, the credentials are sent by my proxy server. Note: http://website.com/login/ does not use Basic Authentication but an HTML form and also note that I know I can achieve something similar using the python requests library but I don't want to merely retrieve the HTML content.

Comment: What do you mean by not merely receiving html? You can only receive what is sent by the server on a particular request. Kindly help me a bit in understanding your question.

Comment: Please check my comment on the below answer @gautamaggarwal

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the `POST` request sent by your browser when you login via *Developer Tools* on your browser. From this, you'll know where the `POST` request goes and which parameters are passed. The login simply needs to make `POST` request to the URL with the parameters required. You could even use cURL to make this request using *cookie jar* to save cookies. After authenticating, you can use the cookie throughout the website.

I'm not sure what you're planning to do after getting past the login. If you simply want to surf the website from your browser without having to login every time, perhaps you can edit the cookie to extend the session after logging in. Or write a *userscript* for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey to make a `POST` request for authentication.

---

**Update: 16/03/2018**

If you are comfortable with your password being exposed, you can setup a simple HTML page with the username and password fields hidden inside a form, and then make the form submit itself using JS.

You could configure nginx as a proxy pretty easily like how gautamaggarwal suggested. But the complication is the authentication part, where the proxy has to authenticate with the third party website on behalf of the user. I'm not so sure if it's possible, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366215/setting-headers-with-nginx-auth-request-proxy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447053/nginx-proxy-authentication-intercept) might help. If the third party website has an API for authentication, this sure would save a lot of trouble :)

Comment: I am using this to give many people access to the site without me having to share my password each time

Comment: I know where the POST request is received and I have successfully authenticated using python-requests before my question. But I have a Linux server running `nginx` and I want to be able to go to http://myserver.com/enter and it redirects me to the site in question already authenticated @sykez

Comment: @mister_dani I've update the answer with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment in sykez answer, I am concluding that you want to redirect the link on your site to some other site which is restricted by authentication for which you have a password. So, What you can do is create a handle like myserver.com/enter for your site in any of the web framework and do it programmatically.

Pick up any one of the mvc framework that is light and can do this job for you. If you know Python, Then flask or bottle will be a good choice. Create a url and a view(controller in other language frameworks like PHP) and make a request from there on. This part will act as proxy to serve your requests which will be authenticated by your proxy code. This is one way to do it and you will have more control this way.
Another way is to use nginx. For which you can look at this link

https://serverfault.com/questions/230749/how-to-use-nginx-to-proxy-to-a-host-requiring-authentication.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I have been trying to do this with django for a while now and I'm not allowed to pass POST requests along with an HttpRedirectReponse, any ideas? And the nginx article would not help as the site does not use Basic Authentication but an HTML form.

Comment: You cannot send post data with redirects in http. Also wont you face issues with site's csrf token if you are submitting the form programmatically? You can re-serve the request on django end. But design here is too poor to be honest. I mean taking request first from client, then making a new request to the server and then reserving to the original client. The content you are serving to the client(browser) from the other site is static in nature? If it was a json or xml or some other form of data structure, It would have been okay. Serving html of other site in active proxy. I dont know man.